# How to compare ES6 Class methods?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback, es6-class

I have written a little pub-sub system in javascript.

And I want to remove now subscribed methods (callbacks):

```
  off(eventName, callback) {

     (this.subscribers)[eventName] = this.subscribers[eventName].filter(event => event !== callback)
       
  },
```

I initialize this so:

```
  Event.on('input_cleared', this.resetValue)
```

While `this.resetValue` is a method inside the same ES6 class:

```
resetValue = () => {
    this.element.value = null
}
```

My store looks like this:

```
input_cleared: Array(2)
0: ƒ ()
1: ƒ ()
```

Now when I want to remove one of these - I think it's not possible - isn't it?
Because the callbacks are anonymous functions.

Is there a way to give the properties of ES6 Classes a name - so they can be removed from a store like that?

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work.

Comment: Yes I tried it. The pubsub works. But I can not remove the callback. Because the .filter(event => event !== callback) is never true. I thing this is because the callback needs to be a named function like with removeEventlistener

Comment: I CAN remove all callbacks. Yes. But not a specific one.

Comment: this has nothing to do with a function being anonymous. As long as you have a pointer to the function (and you do, it's `this.resetValue`), you should be able to remove it by passing the same pointer.

Comment: Can you post a complete example, please? It seems like you are indeed adding the *same* method multiple times, without it being bound to a particular instance. No, this has nothing to do with names.

Comment: You are both right. It actually works. I don't know what I have seen before. Thank you for your fast help. And sorry for that.